# For loop with user input whilst encapsulating in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, input, encapsulation

I want to use a for loop to ask the user for the title, genre and rating of 3 movies and store the information in an array and then display the information back to them. The instance variables are private and getters and setters are used but I don't know how use the getters and setters in the MovieTestDriver class whilst trying to use a for loop to get information.

```
class Movie {

    // Create instance variables for the Movie class.
    private String title;
    private String genre;
    private int rating;

    // Use getters and setters to set and display the variables.
    // Getters.
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }
    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    // Setters.
    public void setTitle(String newTitle) {
        title = newTitle;
    }
    public void setGenre(String newGenre) {
        genre = newGenre;
    }
    public void setRating(int newRating) {
        rating = newRating;
    }

    void playIt() {
        System.out.println(getTitle() + "- Now Playing!");
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MovieTestDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Creates a Movie array of size 3.
    Movie[] movies = new Movie[3];  
    String getTitle;
    String getGenre;
    int getRating;
    // Allows user to enter variables 3 times and populate movie object and store them in an array.
    for (int i=0; i< movies.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the title of Movie " + (i+1));
        getTitle = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the genre of Movie " + (i+1));
        getGenre = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the rating (1-5) of Movie " + (i+1));
        getRaing = input.nextInt();

    }

}
```

Comment: Take the information you received and make a `Movie` object like this `Movie m = new Movie();`. Then use the setters/getters on that object like `m.setTitle(getTitle);` Next, add `m` to your array `movies`.

Answer (score 0):

Use another method to create a movie instance. And mayby another to display the movie:) That way your code will be clean and readable.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Creates a Movie array of size 3.
    Movie[] movies = new Movie[3];  
    // Allows user to enter variables 3 times and populate movie object and store them in an array.
    for (int i=0; i< movies.length; i++) {
       movies[i] = inputMovie(input);
    }
 }

 private static Movie inputMovie(Scanner input){
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        System.out.println("Please enter the title of Movie " + (i+1));
        movie.setTitle(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please enter the genre of Movie " + (i+1));
        movie.setGenre(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please enter the rating (1-5) of Movie " + (i+1));
        movie.setRating(input.nextInt());
        return movie;
 }
```